# Scraping Youtube channel last day videos - bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, youtube

I'm trying to do a Scraping that will return the videos that a particular YouTube channel uploaded on a certain date using bs4 and requests.

Here's the code:

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
    
    all_videos = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC16niRr50-MSBwiO3YDb3RA/videos')
    soup = bs(all_videos.text, 'html.parser')

for video in soup.findAll('h3','yt-lockup-title'):
    print(video)
```

The output is:

```
<h3 class="yt-lockup-title"><a aria-describedby="description-id-721031" class="yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2" data-sessionlink="ei=d1R3Xu7bOfTysAKmsY2IDg&amp;feature=c4-videos-u" dir="ltr" href="/watch?v=ejzQApmABdM" rel="nofollow" title="Coronavirus: People in Beijing begin to head outdoors - BBC News">Coronavirus: People in Beijing begin to head outdoors - BBC News</a><span class="accessible-description" id="description-id-721031"> - Duration: 3 minutes, 8 seconds.</span></h3>
```

How do I extract the title, link, and upload date from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
title = soup.find('title')
link = soup.find('href')
```

or

```
 soup.a.attrs()
```

you will get a dictionary of all attributes, `title` and `href` among them

Comment: It gives me the channel title and its link ... not the video title and link ...

Comment: Based on the html in your post, there is no other title and href in your soup.